# Async Promise chaining with a loop in Node.js & MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, async-await

I recently imported my Database from Sql Server to MongoDB, converting to a full MERN stack. I have a titles_table, a skills_table, and a title_skills_table. The title_skills_table is a 'join' table that holds the _ids of the skills and title tables as some skills can fall under multiple titles.

I'm trying to call all title_skills associated with a particular title, which I've been able to do. What I can't figure out is how to use that title_skills array response to find all the skills by skill_id in the skills_table.

I've tried async waterfall, async chaining, among other things, but it's either just returning an empty error message or breaking the server.

I can do the two calls individually and get a response from each, it's joining them in a looping chain that seems to kill me.

Here's what I currently have:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const Skill = require('../models/Skill');
const TitleSkills = require('../models/TitleSkills');

//Get A Skill by Skill Id
router.get("/skill/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const skill = await Skill.findOne({skill_id: req.params.id}).populate('SkillCategory')
    res.json(skill);
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
});

//Get TitleSkills by TitleId *by itself
// router.get("/title/:id", async (req, res) => {
//   try {
//     const titleSkills = await TitleSkills.find({title_id: req.params.id})
//     res.json(titleSkills)
//   } catch (err) {
//     res.json({ message: err });
//   }
// });

//Get a skill by skill id and through it in an array
const getSkillsByskillId = (id) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const skillsArr = []
  router.get(`/skill/${id}`)
    .then((result) => resolve(skillsArr.push(result.data)))
    return(skillsArr)
    .catch(error => reject(error))
});

//Get all TitleSkills by TitleId and loop each TitleSkill through Skills Table
router.get("/title/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const titleSkills = await TitleSkills.find({title_id: req.params.id})
      .then(titleSkills.forEach((ts) => {
       getSkillsByskillId(ts.skill_id)
      }))
    res.json(titleSkills)
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

#saveme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is equivalent to the OP function of the same name...

```
const getSkillsByskillId = async (id) => {
  const result = await Skill.findOne({skill_id: req.params.id}).populate('SkillCategory')
  return result.data;  // removed OP's extra wrap of the array
}
```

Call it from the route, by mapping over it, collecting promises, and running them together with Promise.all()...

```
router.get("/title/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const skills = await TitleSkills.find({title_id: req.params.id})
    let promises = skills.map(ts => getSkillsByskillId(ts.skill_id));
    let titleSkills = await Promise.all(promises);
    res.json(titleSkills)
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
});
```

Comment: danh... so close!!! I fiddled with it a bit and got it to work. Two things:
1) I used the mongoose findOne() method in `getSkillsByskillId` function instead of the `get()` method: `const result = await Skill.findOne({skill_id: id}).populate('SkillCategory')`. the `get()` method was returning the nulls.
1b) Using the `findOne()` method only requires me to `return result` No array necessary
2) I had to change `let titleSkills = await Promise.all(promises);` because `titleSkills` is already declared for the `find()` method.

Comment: @EvanG - glad it is working. I've edited in the correct endpoint and syntax. The problem in the OP was conceptual regarding the async operations on an array. I probably should have made the answer more conceptual, rather than leave the impression that one could just copy paste and run.

Answer (score 1):

This promise chain is ill-formed:

```js
//Get a skill by skill id and through it in an array
const getSkillsByskillId = (id) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const skillsArr = [];
  router.get(`/skill/${id}`)
    .then((result) => resolve(skillsArr.push(result.data)))
  return (skillsArr)
    .catch(error => reject(error)); // <- never executed
});
```

That `return (skillsArr)` executes immediately after `router.get` is called, returning an empty array.

This modified code returns a promise that resolves to `skillsArr` (there's no need to include a catch block that doesn't do anything besides `reject`):

```js
//Get a skill by skill id and return it in an array
const getSkillsByskillId = (id) => {
  const skillsArr = [];
  return router.get(`/skill/${id}`)
    .then((result) => {
      skillsArr.push(result.data);
      return skillsArr;
    });
};
```

Also, this call to `getSkillsByskillId` ignores the resolve:

```js
    getSkillsByskillId(ts.skill_id)
   }))
```

This probably ought to be something like this:

```js
getSkillsByskillId(ts.skill_id)
  .then(skillsArr => doSomething() );
```

Finally, this block is combining `await` and Promise chain unnecessarily.

```js
const titleSkills = await TitleSkills.find({title_id: req.params.id})
  .then(titleSkills.forEach((ts) => {
    getSkillsByskillId(ts.skill_id);
  }))
```

This is equivalent:

```js
const titleSkills = await TitleSkills.find({title_id: req.params.id});
for (let ts of titleSkills) {
  const skillsArr = await getSkillsByskillId(ts.skill_id);
  // do something with skillsArr
});
```

Comment: hey terrymorse, thanks for answering. I've tried your suggestions several different ways and I still can't seem to get it to work. Mostly it's giving me an error in the console:
`
const skillsArr = await getSkillsByskillId(ts.skill_id);
                        ^^^^^
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
`

Comment: @EvanG Oh, I see my problem. You can only use await directly inside an async function. I've fixed it by replacing the `.forEach()` with a simple `for (...)` block.

Comment: This answer still needlessly instantiates a promise in getSkillsBySkillId.  `get` returns a promise, so there's no need to create one.

Comment: It also suggests unnecessarily that the async operations run on the results of the find be performed in sequence, with an await in a the for loop.

Comment: @danh So `getSkillsBySkillId` could just do `return router.get().then().catch()` ? I see your point about the sequential finds, but it could be that the sequence order is significant.

Comment: @terrymorse, yes, though the OP points out that the mongoose endpoint is findOne. No need for the catch either since it merely rejects the promise.  Real error handling would happen upstream.  Regarding the array, Promise.all() arranges the results in order of the input promises.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Get A skill by skill_id
const getSkillsByskillId = async (id) => {
  const result = await Skill.findOne({skill_id: id}).populate('SkillCategory')
  return result;
}


//Get all TitleSkills by TitleId and then Map each TitleSkill to Skills_Table
router.get("/title/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const titleSkills = await TitleSkills.find({title_id: req.params.id})
    let promises = titleSkills.map(ts => getSkillsByskillId(ts.skill_id));
    let skills = await Promise.all(promises);
    res.json(skills)
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
});
```